# QML Performance issue - Qml is rendered with a large delay on Linux

Tags: multithreading, performance, qt, qml, render

The qml is rendered very slow when running on a Linux machine (nothing wrong when running on Windows). After turning on the QSG_RENDER_TIMING=1 the printouts show a long delay (every time UI content is changed) in blockedForSync (GUI Thread Sync) in the Qt Quick Scene Graph Events:

qt.scenegraph.time.renderer: time in renderer: **total=1158ms**, preprocess=0, updates=0, binding=0, rendering=1158
qt.scenegraph.time.renderloop: Frame rendered with 'threaded' renderloop in 1164ms, sync=0, render=1158, swap=6 - (on render thread)
qt.scenegraph.time.renderloop: Frame prepared with 'threaded' renderloop, polish=0, lock=0, **blockedForSync=1158**, animations=0 - (on Gui thread) QQuickView(0x9705200 active exposed, visibility=QWindow::Visibility(Windowed), flags=QFlags<Qt::WindowType>(Window), title="MyApp", geometry=0,0 1024x768)

The setup is:

qt.scenegraph.general: threaded render loop

qt.scenegraph.general: Using sg animation driver

qt.scenegraph.general: Animation Driver: using vsync: 16.67 ms

qt.scenegraph.general: texture atlas dimensions: 1024x1024

qt.scenegraph.general: R/G/B/A Buffers:    8 8 8 0

qt.scenegraph.general: Depth Buffer:       24

qt.scenegraph.general: Stencil Buffer:     8

qt.scenegraph.general: Samples:            0

qt.scenegraph.general: GL_VENDOR:          VMware, Inc.

qt.scenegraph.general: GL_RENDERER:        Gallium 0.4 on softpipe

qt.scenegraph.general: GL_VERSION:         3.0 Mesa 17.1.5

Comment: Is hardware accelerated graphics enabled on your VM?

Comment: It isn't a VM, it's a Linux running on an Intel chip. I'll check the drivers.

Comment: What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Qt version 5.9.6

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it was indeed a gpu driver issue that was fixed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).